# Enter animation in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have the following views: a ViewPager that show 3 Fragments. The user can scroll horizontaly to see the others Fragment in the ViewPager.
I need to create an animation, when the Activity is created and the ViewPager is populated, that show the Fragments entering from the right side of the screen. 
Is that even possible? Thanks.

XML:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/devices"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp" />
```

Activity:

```
MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter mAdapter = new MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter( this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentArrayList );
mAdapter.setPageWidth(0.33333333f); 
ViewPager devices = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.devices);
devices.setAdapter(sensorAdapter);
```

Adapter:

```
public class MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentsList;

    private float pageWidth = 1;
    public void setPageWidth(float pageWidth) { this.pageWidth = pageWidth; }

    public MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentsList) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragmentsList = fragmentsList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() { 
        return fragmentsList.size(); 
    }       
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position<fragmentsList.size() & fragmentsList.get(position)!=null) {
            return fragmentsList.get(position);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
      return(pageWidth);
    }
}
```

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. I just had to extend ViewPager and do the animation in onDraw.
This code is working as I needed:

```
public class ViewPagerCustom extends ViewPager {

    private Context mContext;
    private boolean startAnimationDone = false;

    public ViewPagerCustom(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public ViewPagerCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    TranslateAnimation anim;
    private void init() {
        metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(metrics.widthPixels+200, 0, 0, 0);
        anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(500);
    }

    private Canvas enterAnimation(Canvas c) {
        startAnimationDone = true;
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.startAnimation(anim);
        }
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        if (startAnimationDone==false) {
            c = enterAnimation(c);
        } 
        super.onDraw(c);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link which might help you:

[Zoom-out page transformer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#zoom-out)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to animation to be only when the ViewPager is created, during the OnCreate.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to the accepted solution but uses the same interpolator and only changes the duration based on a factor. You need to use a ViewPagerCustomDuration in your XML instead of ViewPager, and then you can do this:

```
ViewPagerCustomDuration vp = (ViewPagerCustomDuration) findViewById(R.id.myPager);
vp.setScrollDurationFactor(2); // make the animation twice as slow
```